# How to use a string as a formula in r

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, linear-regression, anova

I'm trying to do an ANOVA of all of my data frame columns against `time_of_day` which is a factor. The rest of my columns are all doubles and of equal length.

```
x = 0
pdf("Time_of_Day.pdf")
for (i in names(data_in)){
  if(x > 9){
    test <- aov(paste(i, "~ time_of_day"), data = data_in)
  }
  x = x+1
}
dev.off()
```

Running this code gives me this error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Where is my code calling `$`? How can I fix this? Sorry, I'm new to r and am quite lost.

My research question is to see if time of day has an affect on brain volume at different ROIs in the brain. Time of day is divided into three categories of morning, afternoon or night.

Edit: SOLVED
 treating the string as a formula will allow this to run although I have been advised to not have this many independent values as it will inflate the statistical results of the model. I am not removing this incase someone has a similar problem with the `aov()` call.

```
x = 0
pdf("Time_of_Day.pdf")
for (i in names(data_in)){
  if(x > 9){
    test <- aov(as.formula(paste(i, "~ time_of_day")), data = data_in)
  }
  x = x+1
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you don't have an ANOVA formula integrated into your aov() function. See the following working example:

```
data_in <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
names(data_in) <- c("first","second","third")

for (i in seq_along(names(data_in))){
  test <- aov(data_in$first ~ data_in$second, data = data_in)
  print(summary(test))
}
```

However, it seems that you tried to calculate an ANOVA for each column, whereas you need at least two variables. That is, a nominal scaled condition variable and an interval scaled dependent variable (e.g. gender and weight). So I'm generally wondering if an ANOVA is the correct method for your question. Anyways, in order to answer this question, sample data and a summary of your research question would be needed.

Comment: My condition variable is `time_of_day` which gives a value of 1 (morning), 2 (afternoon), or 3 (night). The dependent variable is the volume of different areas of the brain. There are 104 different areas of the brain that I want to analyze against `time_of_day`. That's why I'm looping over all the columns in my dataframe. What would I need to change to get this anova to work?

Comment: Also, what do you mean I don't have an ANOVA integrated into my aov() call?

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it runs without the error but I am not sure why?                 `x = 0
pdf("ROIs vs Time of Day(MF).pdf")
for (i in names(data_in)){
  if(x > 9){
    test <- aov(data_in[[i]] ~ data_in$time_of_day)
    print(summary(test))
  }
  x = x+1
}
dev.off()`

Comment: What I posted here is just a piece of working code that is just meant to show where your initial error came from. Your basic problem is that you didn't put in a **model formula** (see here: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html). Most tests in R like regressions or ANOVAs are set together by the same formula syntax, which I would advise you to study first before continuing.

Comment: However, if you have 104 dependent variables, calculating 104 ANOVAs and just taking a look at main effects is not a great idea. I would therefore suggest to consider reducing the amount of dependent variables and also use some kind of post-hoc test like Bonferroni.

Comment: @ jd1338 Yes, I just talked with a stats major and they helped me see how this is a bad idea. I've now reduced my dependent variables down to 6. We will definitely do a post-hoc test too.